# Remove Unwanted Styles from Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, styles

My excel workbook has come upon a limit for excel Styles.  I found VBA code to RemoveTheStyles that were not BuiltIn, applied it and found the Styles were BuiltIn and "SAPBEXstdItem*".

Running this code sadly had no effect.  There are approx 36000 styles that got added about 2 weeks ago.
I don't know the styles were applied.  If I knew how they were created I would try and remove the Style manually but a VBA solution would be preferred.

Regards Peter

```vb
Sub RemoveTheStyles()
 
    Dim style               As style
    Dim l_counter           As Long
    Dim l_total_number      As Long
 
    On Error Resume Next
 
    l_total_number = ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    For l_counter = l_total_number To 1 Step -1
    
        Set style = ActiveWorkbook.Styles(l_counter)
        
        If (l_counter Mod 500 = 0) Then
            DoEvents
            Application.StatusBar = "Deleting " & l_total_number - l_counter + 1 & " of " & l_total_number & " " & style.Name
        End If
        
        If Not style.BuiltIn Then style.Delete
        If Left(style.Name, 13) = "SAPBEXstdItem" Then
            style.Delete
        End If
        Debug.Print style.Name
    Next l_counter
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Debug.Print "READY!"
    
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a code word like `style` as variable name.

This works for me

```vb
Dim sty As Style  '-- don't use style as variable name
For Each sty In ThisWorkbook.Styles
    If sty.BuiltIn = false then 
        sty.delete
    ElseIf sty.Name Like "SAPBEX*" Then 
        sty.delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Ike,  
I should know better than just copy from the website without checking.  I'm down to 49 styles now.  And discovered SAPBEX is not a Built in Style.  No idea what it does/did.
Regards Peter

Comment: If you have the BEX-AddIn running and load BEX-reports these styles are automatically created.